# Can grails domain class include custom criteria in every query?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm creating a domain class that will connect to an existing database. Unfortunately multiple domain objects are stored in the same table (the table is very generic), and I'm trying to find a way to include additional criteria in each query that is made through GORM.

For example, I have an `Article` domain class which exists in the `exp_channel_data` table. The table has `site_id` and `channel_id` columns, which will be used to indicate if the row is actually an Article (where site_id=2, and channel_id=3).

I can setup custom constraints to make sure that validation works properly:

```
static constraints = {
    site_id validator: { it == 2}
    channel_id validator: { it == 3}
}
```

But I want to prevent invalid Articles from even being returned in the first place (keeping things clean, and also for performance reasons).

What I'm envisioning is the ability to override every query that goes out from my domain class, and insert `where site_id=2 and channel_id=3` so that I don't even see invalid rows.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

After using the hibernate-filter plugin (suggested below), this is what I'm using in the domain class to prevent unnecessary entries from being returned.

```
static hibernateFilters = {
    site_idFilter condition: 'site_id=2', default: true
    channel_idFilter condition: 'channel_id=3', default: true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you are describing here, since it's per domain class, this looks to be a perfect situation for using the [Hibernate filters plugin for Grails](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter). This way you can define default constraints to be applied to criteria from those domains. Well worth a look to see if it will meet your needs.

Comment: I've found this plugin to be unreliable in recent Graila versions but YMMV

Comment: @Don It's recently been updated to work with newer versions of Grails according to the plugin page.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore, I'll look into the plugin, thanks for the response. You did mention the criteria of "per domain class", out of curiosity, if this was not per domain class would you have a different suggestion? Thanks again!

Comment: @mmd The only thing that springs to mind in that case would be to use an AST transformation in combination with this plugin. Injecting reusable hibernateFilters. Another option would be to pull apart the plugin and use it as an example for my own implementation that would better meet my specific needs. The main reason for my pointing out the "per domain class" is due to the way the plugin works on a per domain class manner.

Comment: The plugin worked for my use case. I was able to validate that the query includes my filters by using the `logSql = true` setting in DataSource.groovy.